# Setting up Info.plist file in Python and PyObjC, without Xcode

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyobjc, info.plist

I am writing a relatively simple helper application in Python using PyObjC. Because of its simplicity (one main file with some helper functions in another file), I am not using Xcode for development.

However, I would like to set some [`Info.plist` keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html) and I'm not sure how to get my program to find the `Info.plist` file. In particular, I would like to set the `LSUIElement` key to `1` in order to hide my app from the Dock.

I created a file called `Info.plist` in the same directory as my main .py file and added the following text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSUIElement</key>
    <string>1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However, it is not successfully hiding my app from the Dock.

I have two questions:

1. What is the easiest way to verify from within the application
   whether the `Info.plist` file is being read? There could be any number
   of reasons why the Dock icon is not hiding, so is there some simple
   key I can set in `Info.plist` and then evaluate from within my app to
   check whether it is reading the `Info.plist`?
2. What is the correct way to set up an `Info.plist` file when using
   PyObjC? Is there some variable I have to set within my main program
   to tell it where to find the `Info.plist`?

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

===

EDIT: Problem mostly solved -- I think I was just looking at things the wrong way.

It looks like the right way to do things is to *first* bundle my app using py2app, which creates its own `Info.plist` inside the bundle, and *then* edit/replace that `Info.plist` to include the element

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

which I wanted to add. It works like a charm -- my app is now hidden from the Dock. Success!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make use of an Info.plist file the script needs to be part of an application bundle, the system libraries only look for the Info.plist in a particular place in application bundles.

If you start your script from the command-line ("python main.py") the system will use an Info.plist file, but the one embedded in the python installation.

The easiest way to create an application bundle is to use [py2app](http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/), which can build standalone application bundles and has options for customizing the info.plist: http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/tweaking.html.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm using py2app now and I have it working.